# Can't fetch Facebook friends and hometown using Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK for android to fetch the friends list and hometown of a user. I am asking for `read_friendlists`  permission as well as `user_hometown` permission at login. I had even tried with the `user_friends` permission. This is working fine and it is asking for these permisions when I login. I have granted the permission and then after sending the me request like the following:

```
Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (Model.this.session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
            if (user != null) {
                 String hometown = "Location not available";
                 if(user.asMap().get("hometown") != null) { //Intead of user.asMap().get("hometown"), I tried with user.getLocation() as well, no use
                     hometown = user.asMap().get("hometown").toString();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
});
meRequest.executeAsync();
```

But it is always showing `Location not available` even though I have a hometown set to my account.

Now I tried to acces the users friendlist(after getting response from the me request) like the following:

```
final ArrayList<String> friendNames = new ArrayList<String>();
Request friendRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
        for (GraphUser user1 : users) {
            friendNames.add(user1.getName());
        }
    }
});
friendRequest.executeAsync();
```

But the `users` list is always empty resulting in the `friendNames` arrayList to be always empty. What am I doing wrong here? How to rectify it?

Comment: user_hometown gives the current user's hometown. Not his friends hometown. And read_friendlists gives the names of the friendslists that the user have. Not any friends

Comment: 1. I am trying to get the user's home town, not his friend's
2. I even tried with the user_friends permission first. Still didn't work

Comment: user_friends works. But it will only return friends that are also using your app. You can not get all friends.

Comment: Oh.. Then that might be it.. Thanks. But why can't I get my hometown?

Comment: I would check what is returned from Facebook.